# Learn ros doing exercices

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started to learn ROS and I think the best way to learn it is doing things with it. I get bored if I read or watch videos without doing anything.

Could you recommend me a book, online course or tutorial where exercises that I can do and check my results?

By the way I'm running ROS Lunar in an Ubuntu 16.04.4 and I want to learn ROS and how to connect it with Gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296646/learn-ros-doing-exercices/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I learned the fundamentals of ROS (Kinetic) + Gazebo via:

- [ROS Website Tutorials (online)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)
- [Programming Robot with ROS: A Practical Introduction (book)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449323898)
- Gazebo Website Tutorials (online)

  - [Categorized Tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials)
  - [All Tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/browse)

---

> I've just started to learn ROS and I think the best way to learn it is doing things with it. I get bored if I read or watch videos without doing anything.

In that case (I too struggle to learn things in a vacuum), I recommend that you identify a project/goal that interests you, *e.g. face-tracking turret that tracks, identifies, and shoots foam darts at (specific) coworkers.*

Once you have an interesting goal, try to achieve it using ROS. You will have a strong incentive to learn about the parts of the ROS ecosystem that are relevant to your goal.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1